# Binary Search Tree in Prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-search-tree

I have to make a binary search tree using Prolog that contains the following features: insert, search, pre-order, in-order and post-order. My problem is that I don't even know where to begin. I've tried looking online for information, but I don't understand enough for anything to make sense to me. I have a working BST in python and I thought I would be able to somehow translate that into Prolog but I'm not having any luck with it. If anyone could give me any pointers on how to even start this, it would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Are you in a class for Prolog? Then what has the teacher taught you?

Comment: @GuyCoder I'm not in a class for Prolog, we were just told to create a BST in an OO based language and a Logic based language. We haven't been taught anything.

Comment: I would suggest focusing on a small subset of the problem instead of trying to port existing code to Prolog. For example, in Prolog how would one represent a node in a tree? Try starting there and building up.

Comment: have you ever wrote any code in Prolog? do you know what Prolog terms are?

Comment: @WillNess no, I’m afraid I haven’t. I’m doing a semester at a different university as part of my course and I’ve got no choice in the matter unfortunately. I don’t really know anything about Prolog, trying to learn but it’s proving very difficult for me!

Comment: then it is beyond my comprehension how is it expected of you to learn a semester worth of material on your own for this one assignment, in a day or two. do you know what unification is?

Comment: @WillNess I was told the majority of the marks are going for the comparing and contrasting of the two different implementations, but I still need to submit code for it - it makes no sense to me either, trust me! I do not know what unification is, no.

Comment: you're welcome to try reading e.g. [a few of my recent Prolog answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a849891%20%5bprolog%5d), where I tried to talk about very basic stuff concisely (not the last one, start with the one before last, and the one linked inside it). see how it's going, feel free to ask for clarifications as needed.

Comment: @WillNess ah thank you!! I’ll have a look at them and see what they do for me, I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: but this whole situation isn't right. your teachers clearly expect someone else to do their job for them (for you).

Comment: @WillNess I completely agree with you but unfortunately I can’t really do anything about it. The joys of being a foreign student..

Comment: Related question: [Procedural and declarative reading of facts and predicates in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53797814/1243762)