# Procedural and declarative reading of facts and predicates in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am not really sure how to go about giving the procedural and declarative reading of facts and predicates. I was wondering if anyone could give me some guidance on how to write them.

Here is my code for inserting a `Key` into a binary tree:

```
insert(Key, null, tree(key, null, null)).
insert(Key, tree(Root, LST, RST), tree(Root, NewLST, RST)) :-
    Key < Root,
    insert(Key, LST, NewLST).
insert(Key, tree(Root, LST, RST), tree(Root, LST, NewRST)) :-
    Key > Root,
    insert(Key, RST, NewRST).
```

Comment: You are looking for someone to explain your own code to you?

Comment: @ScottHunter no, I understand my own code, my problem is that I don't know how to put it into English. Maybe I should rephrase.

Comment: If you can explain it in a different language, do so & have it translated into English.

Comment: @ScottHunter In Prolog there is a what is known as how a predicate is read (past tense). Certain books explain how to write the reading of a predicate. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53412988/1243762) I did it for some of the statements. They can be found by searching for the word `reads`.

Comment: @GuyCoder yes that is what I’m looking for, how a predicate reads!! I didn’t know what to look up in order to find that, maybe this will help me, thank you for your comment!

Comment: @GuyCoder yes it is, thank you again. I can tell you honestly that it would be very much appreciated but do not stress about it too much, I am just grateful for any help I can get.

Comment: You are missing a clause. What happens if you add the same key twice?

Comment: If you query `insert(5,null,T).` should it not be `T = tree(5,null,null).` ?

Comment: Of interest: Power of Prolog - [Reading Prolog Programs](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/reading)

Comment: Of interest: Comment - [Declarative versus Procedural](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/projects/ALP/newsletter/archive_93_96/comment/decl.html)

Comment: Of interest: [The Art of Prolog](https://books.google.com/books?id=w-XjuvpOrjMC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=prolog+binary+tree+declarative+reading&source=bl&ots=4ZB-1HF0Oo&sig=M4nt5zXuOIELoPaX5S_jAuto3_w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw9ferpaPfAhXkg-AKHSPGBekQ6AEwBXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=prolog%20binary%20tree%20declarative%20reading&f=false) Declarative reading of binary tree.

Comment: @GuyCoder I know there are a few bugs, perfect code is not the most important thing for me right now but I will try and fix them at some stage. I only started learning prolog two days ago so I’m still trying to wrap myself around it!

Comment: @GuyCoder thank you for all your suggestions of interest, I will have a look at all of them! You are a very helpful person, thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: There are bugs with OP code in the question for a binary tree. The question was for the reading of the Prolog code not the fixing of the code.

Procedural reading based on [Bratko](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/722841722), Section 9.3 `Insertion and deletion in a binary tree` pg. 231

`T` is a binary tree. A tree can be empty, have only a root, have one leaf, or have two leafs.

---

```
insert(Key, null, tree(key, null, null)).
```

Procedural reading:
The result of inserting `Key` to the empty tree `null` is the tree `tree(key,null,null)`.

---

```
insert(Key, tree(Root, LST, RST), tree(Root, NewLST, RST)) :-
    Key < Root,
    insert(Key, LST, NewLST).
```

Proceduralreading:
If the root of `T` is greater than `Key` then insert `Key` into the left subtree of `T`.

---

```
insert(Key, tree(Root, LST, RST), tree(Root, LST, NewRST)) :-
    Key > Root,
    insert(Key, RST, NewRST).
```

Procedural reading:
If the root of `T` is less than `Key` then insert `Key` into the right subtree of `T`.

---

Declarative reading based on [The Art of Prolog](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/912229865), Section 3.4 `Binary Trees` pg. 72

Declarative reading:

- `Key` can be inserted into a null tree
- or if it can be inserted into the left subtree if `Key` is a less than the value at node
- or if it can be inserted into the right subtree if `Key` is a greater than the value at node.

---

A personal note on why writing the declarative meaning is important.

When trying to understand the procedural meaning, for me it explains how the code works in the procedural mode where the input parameters are set and a value is returned.

```
?- insert(5,null,Tree).
Tree = tree(5, null, null) ;
false.
```

Note: I fixed a bug with the OP code to get that query to work as demonstarted.

or

```
?- insert(3,tree(5,null,null),Tree).
Tree = tree(5, tree(3, null, null), null) ;
false.
```

When trying to understand the declarative meaning, for me it explains how the code works in other [modes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modes) where the result is given and one or more of the parameters are variables, or all of the parameters are variables (can't remember what this is called, I think it is most general question).

In this case when writing the declarative meaning, and trying queries like

```
?- insert(Key,X,tree(5,null,null)).
Key = 5,
X = null ;
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] _8894<5
ERROR:    [8] insert(_8920,tree(5,_8930,null),tree(5,null,null)) at c:/users/eric/documents/projects/prolog/so_question_101.pl:6
ERROR:    [7] <user>
   Exception: (8) insert(_8238, _8240, tree(5, null, null)) ? creep
```

and

```
?- insert(Key,Tree,tree(Root,Left,Right)).
Key = Root,
Tree = Left, Left = Right, Right = null ;
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] _12488<_12490
ERROR:    [8] insert(_12514,tree(_12522,_12524,_12526),tree(_12530,_12532,_12534)) at c:/users/eric/documents/projects/prolog/so_question_101.pl:6
ERROR:    [7] <user>
% Execution Aborted
```

tells me that one or more of these need to be addressed:

1. The modes need to be defined for the predicate
2. Guard statements need to be added to avoid the errors
3. The predicate name needs to be changed from being procedural to declarative.
4. The code needs to be made [pure](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/purity)
5. The means of evaluation needs to be changed, e.g. using [constraint programming](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clp) or something else.

---

So by learning how to add modes to code to go from procedural to declarative, one can also look in the reverse of how can this can help to write better code in procedural languages.

When I write code for programming languages that do not have [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) as a [first class notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type#Programming_languages_with_algebraic_data_types) such as Java I have to use many `if` or `switch` statements to cover all of the combinations of the data structure. Now there are cases where the code runs correctly with out an `else` or `default` but to make the code better when I write an `if` or `switch`, I always add the `else` or `default` with `assert (false)` and run the code. If the assert fails it typically indicates that my reasoning about the code was wrong, and I either rewrite the code or change the assert to a comment explaining why the `else` or `default` case can occur but is not needed.

Comment: I like declarative readings that discuss how the arguments are _related_. `insert/3` shows us how a key is related to a tree with and a tree without that key. The three clauses become the three cases of, a key with an empty tree, and a key less and greater than the root of the tree. The declarative reading helps show how the ideas of insert and removal are related, like how `append/3` actually shows you not just how to combine two lists into a third but also how to split one list into two pieces, by thinking in terms of how it relates three things together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your understanding of my question, it is very helpful and I really appreciate it, you’ve helped so much!